# UIView animate in ONLY ONE view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-animation

So I am using container views in swift to get an overlay view that is shared between a number of view controllers in a navigation controller.

The way this works is that I have a number of subviews that create the "background" for the flow. Above these views I have a container view that has a navigation controller embedded within it. This navigation controller takes the user through the onboarding process via a number of view controllers. Above this container view is the "progress view," which has its leading edge aligned with the superview's leading edge and which increases in width as the user navigates through the onboarding processes until, eventually, the bar's width is equal to the width of the screen and the user has created their profile. 
Here is an example of how it looks:
[Skip to 1:53 to see the main issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqEh7Og_jsU&feature=youtu.be)

This is what the containing view controller looks like. Note the layering of the background, then container view, then progress bar view:
[image]

This view controller has a function called `updateProgressBar` which takes a percentage of the screen width to animate to and then performs the animation.

```
func updateProgressBar(to percentAsDecimal: CGFloat!) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        self.progressBarWidth.constant = self.view.frame.width * percentAsDecimal
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

**The issue:**
Because the contained navigation controller is pushing a new view controller during the progress bar's animation, when this new view controller lays out its subviews, this laying out is animated.

**What I've tried:**
I've created custom classes that are subclasses of UIView that use the `UIView.performWithoutAnimation` function to avoid this animating of subviews.

```
import UIKit

class NonAnimatingView: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            super.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
}
```

I've done something similar with buttons.

```
import UIKit

class NonAnimatingButton: UIButton {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            super.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to do this with a UISearchBar, however, some of the animations are resolved, but not all.

```
import UIKit

class NonAnimatingSearchBar: UISearchBar {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            super.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }

    override func addSubview(_ view: UIView) {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            super.addSubview(view)
        }
    }

    override func insertSubview(_ view: UIView, at index: Int) {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            super.insertSubview(view, at: index)
        }
    }

    override func insertSubview(_ view: UIView, aboveSubview siblingSubview: UIView) {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            super.insertSubview(view, aboveSubview: siblingSubview)
        }
    }

    override func insertSubview(_ view: UIView, belowSubview siblingSubview: UIView) {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            super.insertSubview(view, belowSubview: siblingSubview)
        }
    }

    override func sendSubviewToBack(_ view: UIView) {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            super.sendSubviewToBack(view)
        }
    }

    override func bringSubviewToFront(_ view: UIView) {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            super.bringSubviewToFront(view)
        }
    }

    override func exchangeSubview(at index1: Int, withSubviewAt index2: Int) {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            super.exchangeSubview(at: index1, withSubviewAt: index2)
        }
    }
}
```

I've also made sure that any layout changes called before the navigation controller view controllers are pushed are NOT being animated:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        femaleButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
        maleButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
        otherGenderButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
        femaleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        maleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        otherGenderButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        nextButton.layer.cornerRadius = nextButton.frame.height/2
    }
}
```

**What I'm wondering:**
Is there something I can call instead of `UIView.animate` so that I can animate things within the specified view controller without effecting all view controllers currently visible? If not, what is the best way to remedy this issue?

Comment: Why don't you use CAShapeLayer and CoreAnimation instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up taking @rs7 's advice and used a `CAShapeLayer` instead. Instead of using interface builder, I went ahead and create a CAShapeLayer and added it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

```
var progressBar: CAShapeLayer!

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    progressBar = CAShapeLayer()
    progressBar.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: view.safeAreaInsets.top)
    progressBar.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    progressBar.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    progressBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.secondaryColor.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(progressBar)
}
```

Then I went ahead and updated `updateProgressBar` to resize a `CALayer` instead of an `NSLayoutConstraint` constant.

```
func updateProgressBar(to percentAsDecimal: CGFloat!) {
    let newWidth = view.bounds.width * percentAsDecimal
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
        self.progressBar.bounds.size.width = newWidth
    })
    CATransaction.commit()
    let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
    anim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    anim.fillMode = .forwards
    anim.duration = 0.25
    anim.fromValue = NSValue(cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: progressBar.bounds.width, height: view.safeAreaInsets.top))
    anim.toValue = NSValue(cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: view.safeAreaInsets.top))
    progressBar.add(anim, forKey: "anim")
}
```

Now, there is no longer a need for my custom `NonAnimatingView`, `NonAnimatingButton`, or `NonAnimatingSearchBar`. :)